# How to process geometrical data from a spatial database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, geometry, spatialite

I'm working on a small geographical project, and I'm having a small trouble with one thing. I have a spatial database (SpatiaLite) in which I store some geometries (it has geometry columns). Specifically - polygons. They are stored of course as BLOB objects in the database. Now I would like to query the database, retrieve this geometry object and the process it so that I can for example plot it later. The way I see it, there are two ways of doing that: either extract the raw BLOB, and then decode it somehow, or fetch its well-known text representation using the SpatiaLite AsText (Geometry) command. The result would look like:

```
POLYGON ((0, 5), (3, 4) ...)
```

Not really sure which way is better, any advice how to approach this? The implementation is done in Python 2.7.

Comment: Map drawing libraries typically know about WKB. How do you want to plot them?

Comment: Until now I just used matplotlib.

Comment: Try one, and if you can't get it to work come back for help.

Comment: But it's not a matter of trying and error, the thing is, that I'm stuck and I just don't know how to proceed with either one.

Comment: your suggestion, "fetch its well-known text representation using the SpatiaLite AsText (Geometry) command", seems like a good place to start.

Comment: shapely can load wkb or wkt if your having trouble parsing.  http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

Comment: Yes, exactly what I needed, I dunno how could I miss it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's Spatialite's BLOB structure : http://gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html